# WPF: GDI drawing in other process flickers

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi

There are quite some topics available about GDI drawing and flickering issues, but I haven´t been able to find any regarding drawing in an other process.

**The issue**

Basically I´m trying to draw to a Hwnd using Graphics.FromHwnd. This works perfectly, but there is a lot of flickering involved. The application I´m trying to draw on is a game (not made by me) and  has quite a high refresh rate, unlike forms.

**Attempts**

I´ve tried doing the drawing both using a GDI.Rectangle function that used the HDC to draw and using Graphics.DrawRectangle to draw to the Hwnd. I don't notice a difference in performance but 'Graphics' seems a bit easier in use since it doesn't need gdi32.dll to draw shapes, unlike GDI.

I've also tried doublebuffering but yet again I do not notice any difference.

To me it seems that the doublebuffering is not working because of the fact that I'm trying to draw in such a high refresh rate window.

**Question**

- Is it possible to get the window's refresh rate and use that for a timer to update the graphic?
- is it possible to make graphics 'stick' until updated so they don't automatically disappear?

If anyone knows how to do this, or knows other solutions to get rid of the flickering I would appreciate the help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this abpit WPF? Isn't it GDI+? Anyway how did you try double buffering? It has to be done on target application (**at least** window associated with GDI device context should have WS_EX_COMPOSITED window style).

Comment: @Adriano "Isn't it GDI+?": To be honest I have no clue... I thought I was using GDI but after some research I think I'm actually using GDI+. I'm gonna check if I can change that to GDI to run some tests there. I think I might try and set WS_EX_COMPOSITED on the game's window if that's possible. I'll try that as soon as I get home from work and post the results.

Comment: I've set WS_EX_COMPOSITED on the game's window. It does reduce flickering a bit, but there is still a decent amount there. I think this is because I'm using a timer to do the drawing. Would it be possible to make something like a hook for the drawing event of the game's window?

Comment: I think you should post some code, GDI+ itself is pretty slow and I don't think some general advice may really help you. For example if you create resources (like brushes) for each paint event that will degreade performance a lot. Moreover a timer may be (or not) a good solution but to keep refresh rate high you may invalidate window after each painting (to "simulate" paint loop used for example in DirectX).

Comment: I'll post some code as soon as I can. Something I'm wondering though: A game invalidates the window after each frame correct? Wouldn't that interfere with invalidating the window after each painting by GDI+?

Comment: I didn't understand before what you're doing. That window is painted by game AND you write there too. I never tried something like that and it may not be such easy as I thought (with performance in mind). Every time I had to interop GDI+ with a context shared with something else I always had more issues than benefits. Did you try how it works with "plain" GDI in C?

Comment: Ah yes I should've been clearer about that. I haven't tried GDI yet but that'll be my next step. I've also been thinking about using OpenGL to draw to the Hwnd, but to me it seems that it will clear everything as soon as the game invalidates the window, so whatever technique I'd use, I would have to somehow sync the drawing with the game to prevent flickering.

Comment: Yes but it may be not so easy. Especially because game itself may use its own technique to manage its own window (= double buffering) or directly work with GPU so what you do may interfer...

Comment: True, I'm going to look if there are hooks for invalidation calls on windows or anything else that has to do with calls to the GPU by an application. If that's not possible I'd probably have to draw on a separate overlay of some kind.

Comment: Not bad idea, to track game window and to keep a transparent window exactly above it should be easier (and "safer").

Comment: Ok I'll do my research and post back if I find a solution or decide to go with the transparent window. Thank you for the help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I've come to the conclusion that using a transparent window will suit my case best. Here's how I came to that conclusion:

I've used an application to read window events to check if there was any continuous event stream that could be the window invalidation, but there wasn't.

I did find out a way that should make it possible to actually read when the game invalidates the window, but it's kind of a hack: It's possible to replace the game's d3d9.dll file with your own, calling all the original functions, but catching the events. I don't have any details on how or even if it works since having to distribute a dll to end-users is not an option for me, not to mention that this is in fact hacking.